# JSON deserialization with C#

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a JSON file but something is not working. The object results is null after the execution.

```cs
FilePath = openfiledialog.FileName;
JSONfile = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);

JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
SearchResults results = js.Deserialize<SearchResults>(JSONfile);
```

[image]

[image]

```
"searchResults": [
    {
        "startTime": 1604466366253,
        "parameter": {
            "name": "CntIOParts",
            "value": 0,
            "datatype": "int"
        }
    },
    {
        "startTime": 1604478998001,
        "parameter": {
            "name": "CntIOParts",
            "value": 0,
            "datatype": "int"
        }
    }]
```

Comment: In your classes, `SearchResults` is an object which contains a single array called `results`. In your JSON, the root element is presumably an object (although you omit this) which contains a single array called `searchResults`. See the difference? The name of the `UnixTime`/`startTime` member doesn't match up either.

Comment: Also `parameter` vs `parameters`.

Comment: I guess you are using wrong thing to deserialize json. Use System.Text.Json/ Newtonsoft Json

Comment: The `JavaScriptSerializer` type was meant to support internal communication in AJAX type applications, it was not meant to be a full JSON library with all the bells and whistles. Instead, either use `System.Text.Json` or the Json.net nuget package, depending on framework type and version.

Comment: I do agree with @LasseV.Karlsen,
you have to use a fully dedicated package for json, and you have a lot of trusted ones, or else you use System.Text.Json

Comment: Also, `parameters` is a list in your C#, but an object in your JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with object result being null is because, Serialize doesn't know which object to map on which one. What you need to have is, rename your `class` properties similar to that of in the `json` that you have. Moreover, your json is not in a correct format. You should not have the name of the outer-most property (`searchResults`). The other issue in your models is, you have a `List<Parameter>` in your model but in your json, `Parameter` is not an array, so you should make that accept an object instead of an array.

So, in order to get it correctly parsed, make it look like this:

```
[
    {
        "startTime": 1604466366253,
        "parameter": {
            "name": "CntIOParts",
            "value": 0,
            "datatype": "int"
        }
    },
    {
        "startTime": 1604478998001,
        "parameter": {
            "name": "CntIOParts",
            "value": 0,
            "datatype": "int"
        }
    }
]
```

And your models should like like this:

```
public partial class SearchResult
{
    public long startTime { get; set; }

    public Parameter parameter { get; set; }
}

public partial class Parameter
{

    public string name { get; set; }

    public long value { get; set; }
    
    public string datatype { get; set; }
}
```

Plus, instead using `JavaScriptSerializer` I would recommend using the `Newtonsoft.Json` library to parse the objects.

```
FilePath = openfiledialog.FileName;
JSONfile = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);

var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SearchResult>>(JSONfile);
```

Comment: You are right. I just got to know the Visual Studio feature "Paste JSON as classes", which saved me time.